# How to structure a project with sub-projects?

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, architecture, frameworks

I am creating a SaaS web app for online scheduling, and want to create multiple niche versions of this SaaS for different kind of businesses.

I want to know what's the best project structure for this.

I'm considering using `forks` or `branches` but I can't really decide what's the best for this scenario.

The sub-projects need to stay updated with the "core" SaaS project.

That means that when I fix a bug or add a new module (such as shopping features or theming) to the main project it is automatically available to all the other running sub-projects.

The features are going to be modular so new ones can be added or old ones removed.

Anyone can give me a light here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use Lerna or yarn workspaces to share different modules across your applications.

Lerna: https://github.com/lerna/lerna

Yarn: https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/

example: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/next/packages